# I have a strange error

Tags: sql, database

I believe it has something to do with my foreign keys, but I don't really understand whats wrong.. This is the error I get:

ERROR 1005 (HY000) at line 1: Can't create table 'cse156.Accounts' (errno: 150)

```
 CREATE TABLE `AccountType`(
   `AccountType` varchar(255)NOT NULL,
   `Label` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   `BaseAPR` float(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT'0.0',
   `BaseFee` float(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0',
   PRIMARY KEY (`AccountType`)
 );

CREATE TABLE `Accounts`(
   `AccountID` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
   `AccountType` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   `Balance` float(10) Default '0',
   `DateofCreation` varchar(255),
   `AprAdjustment` float(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT'0.0',
   `FeeAdjustment` float(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT'0.0',
   PRIMARY KEY (`AccountID`),
   FOREIGN KEY (`AccountType`) REFERENCES AccountTypes(`AccountType`)
 );

 INSERT INTO `Accounts` VALUES (867001,'RIRA08',543.23,'2008/03/01',0.0,0.0),(530900,'RIRA08',123.00,'2008/04/05',0.125,3.50),(321455,'GCD1009',1232123.12,'2002/01/05',-1.25,0.0),(392108,'RPSA',450.00,'1994/06/09',0.0,15.00),(32948,'RPSA',25.00,'1997/08/03',0.25,2.50),(90490001,'GCD1009',1000000.50,'2005/03/06',1.25,0.50);



 INSERT INTO `AccountType` VALUES('RIRA08','Roth IRA',2.05,10.00),('GCD1009','Golden Years         Certificate of Deposit',5.05,0.00),('MIRA09','Roth IRA',3.2,0.00),('RPSA','Savings    Advantage',1.85,0.00);

 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Customers`;

 CREATE TABLE `Customers` (
   `CustomerID` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
   `CustomerFirstName` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   `CustomerLastName` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   `Address` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   `Email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   `Flag` varchar(1) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`CustomerID`),
   FOREIGN KEY (`AccountID`) REFERENCES Accounts(`AccountID`)
 );

 INSERT INTO Customers VALUES (829304,'Anthony','Rizzo','123 A Street,Omaha, NE, 68116','rizzo@cubs.com,arizzo@iowacubs.com','S'),(423904,'Starlin','Castro','456 B Ave., Chicago, IL, 67777','scastro@gmail.com','P'),(423431,'Darwin','Barney','7G North,Le City,ON,E5F456','dbar@yahoo.com,barn@mlb.com,db01@unl.edu','S');

 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `CustomerAccounts`;

 CREATE TABLE `CustomerAccounts` (
   `CustomerID` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
   `AccountID` int(11)  DEFAULT '0',
   FOREIGN KEY (`AccountID`) REFERENCES Accounts(`AccountID`),
   FOREIGN KEY (`CustomerID`) REFERENCES Customers(`CustomerID`)
 );

 INSERT INTO `CustomerAccounts`VALUES(829304,0), (423904,867001),(423904,530900),(423431,90490001),(423431,32948),(423431,392108);
```

Comment: Where is the `Accounts` table? You have no table `Accounts` even though it is referenced in two FK's.  Further, you don't have a column `AccountID` in the `Customers` table, even though you attempt to add a FK constraint on it.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski That was my bad, I just forgot to copy that code, but the problem still stands

Answer (score 2):

Errno 150 is a `FOREIGN KEY` error, usually due to a data type mismatch or missing column. In your case, it is a typo in a table name.

You have an incorrect table name `AccountTypes` instead of `AccountType` in the `Accounts` FK definition:

```
 FOREIGN KEY (`AccountType`) REFERENCES AccountTypes(`AccountType`)
 -------------------------------------------------^^^  Oops, should be AccountType
```

A little further down the line, the `Customers` table will fail next because there is no `AccountID` column:

```
 CREATE TABLE `Customers` (
   `CustomerID` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
   `CustomerFirstName` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    /* Add the AccountID column for your FK definition */
   `AccountID` INT(10),
   `CustomerLastName` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   `Address` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   `Email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   `Flag` varchar(1) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`CustomerID`),
   FOREIGN KEY (`AccountID`) REFERENCES Accounts(`AccountID`)
 );
```

A little further still, you'll have a problem here because the data type `INT(11)` of `AccountID` doesn't match `Accounts.AccountID` which is `INT(10)`:

```
 CREATE TABLE `CustomerAccounts` (
   `CustomerID` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
   /* Make this INT(10) to match the referenced column */
   `AccountID` int(10)  DEFAULT '0',
   FOREIGN KEY (`AccountID`) REFERENCES Accounts(`AccountID`),
   FOREIGN KEY (`CustomerID`) REFERENCES Customers(`CustomerID`)
 );
```